# How can I show the list of videos stored on JWPlayer?

Tags: jwplayer

I have a web application which uploads videos on JWPlayer. But I don't know how to properly show them. I'm storing in the database the list of video keys uploaded by the users and I would like to show the list of videos for each of them.
Something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation for the Management API's [`/v1/videos/list`](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/reference/v1/methods/videos/list.html). That'll get you a list of videos and their metadata (like duration, title, date, etc).

From there you can use the [Delivery API](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/docs/delivery-api-reference/) to get the thumbnails (or poster images) for each video.