# Formatting a JWPlayer to Provide a Carousel of Videos in Playlist

Tags: javascript, carousel, jwplayer, video-player

Good day, all,

I've already read the page at [How can I show the list of videos stored on JWPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257244/how-can-i-show-the-list-of-videos-stored-on-jwplayer) but don't fully understand it. The reference links in the suggested solutions no longer lead to the JWPlayer documentation they referenced 4 years ago. When searching the JWPlayer developer docs, I'm not finding what I need. This may be my ADHD brain getting to me, but my Google-fu has failed me.

PROBLEM: Using JWPlayer I would like to set up a video display on a landing page with a carousel directly beneath the player window. That carousel would display clickable thumbnails of all other videos in the playlist.

COMPLICATIONS: I've been spacing a lot of words while researching; very embarrassing. So it may simple be due to my poor word choices when searching for a solution.

WHAT IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE: Following is an image (just a mock-up) of how I'd like JWPlayer to look upon embedding it onto the page:

[image: A video player with a carousel of clickable video thumbnails where the thumbnails are part of the same playlist as the video that shows up in the JWPlayer video player.]

I keep thinking this should be easy but I've spent hours combing the Developer docs and am hitting a brick wall.

Does anyone have any insight into the functionality I'm describing or is able to tell me what words you would search for answers with?

I tried exploring and searching the JWPlayer documentation here: https://docs.jwplayer.com/players/docs/jw8-overview but I keep getting either 0 results or tons of results that do not relate to "JWPlayer custom display" or "video thumbnail carousel".

I was expecting JWPlayer to have simple tools in their API allowing for such formatting.